# User session in Outlook Add-in on Safari

Tags: cookies, safari, session-cookies, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We have developed an Outlook Add-in for Outlook Web App that requires users to log in via Office 365 (oauth2). However on Safari, the setting “Prevent cross-site tracking”, which is enabled by default, prevents 3rd party cookies, and therefore it is not possible to establish a user session (as the session id is managed via cookies).

If we disable the setting “Prevent cross-site tracking”, then it works fine, so it is clear that this is the issue.

What is the advice from Microsoft on how to enable sessions for Outlook Add-ins where 3rd party cookies are disabled (as is the case in Safari)?

Comment: From what I read, 'prevent cross-site tracking' isn't synonymous with blocking third party cookies.  It depends on if you have visited the site recently, and I've seen posts that suggest just retrying the call may work (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423774/error-aadsts50058-a-silent-sign-in-request-was-sent-but-no-user-is-signed-in).  Are you using MSAL library?

Comment: Recommend you to go through https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/safari/sfri40732/13.0/mac/10.15 and https://webkit.org/blog/7675/intelligent-tracking-prevention/ to have a better understanding of “Prevent cross-site tracking” functionality in Safari. We would like you to confirm if this is a one time issue and log in flow works after enabling “Prevent cross-site tracking” back?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read the articles you provided, and learned that the cookie restrictions are only applied if the user hasn’t interacted directly with the website. So I visited the website and then the add-in worked as intended. Apologies for hitting SO before reading the docs! In response to your question - if I do not visit the website, then re-enabling "Prevent cross-site tracking" breaks the log in flow again (as I would expect it to). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GwynHowell Is there anything else you need from our side?

Comment: We still have the issue where users who have not visited the site first are unable to log in. We are also experiencing that if Safari is closed and re-opened, then the cookies are removed, and therefore same problem - unable to log in. Do you have any advice or best practices on how to handle the case where a user has not visited the website in advance of opening the outlook add-in?

Comment: It has been put on our backlog. Unfortunately, we have no timelines to share at this point.

Comment: Any update on this? It seems to affect Outlook in iOS 14 too, and it not possibly to fix by allowing cross-site tracking

Comment: We worked around this by forcing user login. You have to use Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync method to retain session and prevent cross site issues. See docs here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins.

Comment: @GwynHowell Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: @camden_kid yes - see my previous comment. You have to use the ms libs to display a dialog. You cannot do it using traditional js. Unfortunately, this means more dev work but we managed to get it working on the end.